# Regex to match host request

Tags: regex, varnish

Given this VCL code in Varnish 3.0.2:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.http.host !~ "^(?i)(www|m|mobile)\.example\.com$" || req.http.host !~ "^(?i)example\.com$") {
    error 403 "Forbidden";
  }
  return(lookup);
}
```

can anyone explain why I'm getting 403s on "www.example.com"?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know varnish and its syntax, but I interpret `||` to be an logical `OR`. So `www.example.com` does not match the second alternative ==> it is true and you enter the `if`.

Probably you wanted a logical **AND**? If both is not true, then 403?

So try:

```
if (req.http.host !~ "^(?i)(www|m|mobile)\.example\.com$" && req.http.host !~ "^(?i)example\.com$") {
    error 403 "Forbidden";
  }
```